# OleDb UPDATE query

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledbcommand

I am new to using Access Databases in C# and wanted to know if it was possible to replace this code

```
string sql = "UPDATE Volunteer SET
VolunteerName =  @VolunteerName, 
NickName = @NickName,
ContactNo = @ContactNo
WHERE VolunteerID = @VolunteerID ";

dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VolunteerName", txtLastName.Text);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NickName", txtFirstName.Text);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", txtContact.Text);
dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VolunteerID", txtVolunteerID.Text);
```

with something similar to this

```
string sql = "UPDATE Volunteer SET
VolunteerName = "+ txtLastName.Text +", 
NickName = "+ txtFirstName.Text +",
ContactNo = "+ txtContact.Text +"
WHERE VolunteerID = "+ txtVolunteerID.Text ";

dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);
```

Comment: Bad, bad, bad idea.  The correct version using parameters is the correct approach.  The only tweak is to add the values with the correct type rather than using `AddWIthValue()`.

Comment: google `sql injection attack` as to get knowledge about why your proposed code is bad.